# Do I really need a separable dual to extract a weakly convergent subsequence out of a bounded sequence in a reflexive Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, calculus-of-variations

In my functional analysis course we proved the Banach-Alaoglu theorem and this corollary :

> Banach-Alaoglu theorem :Let $X$ be a separable Banach spaceLet
> $\{f_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $X'$, then there exists a
> weakly*-convergent subsequence  $\{f_{n_k}\}$ to some $f \in X'$.
>
> Corollary :Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space such that the dual $X'$
> is separable. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $X$, then there
> exists a weakly-convergent subsequence  $\{x_{n_k}\}$ to some $x\in$
> $ X$.

The proof of the corollary consisted in applying the Banach-Alaoglu theorem to the spaces $X'$ and $X''$ and for that we needed $X'$ to be separable.

Now in my Calculus of variations course as a summary of important results from functional analysis I have this theorem withouth proof:

> Theorem :Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach  Then every   bounded sequence
> has a weakly convergent subsequence.

**which I think it should be the corollary above so I wonder, is this wrong? The hypothesis that the dual $X'$ is separable is missing. Or maybe my version of the corollary was an easier-to-prove one?**

Comment: The theorem is true without separability.

Comment: @geetha290krm Do I need a non-separable Banach-Alaoglu to prove the theorem? Why would people add the X' separable hypothesis?

Comment: See 1) implies 4) under PROPERTIES in this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: The unit ball in a reflexive (separable or not) Banach space is weakly compact. The rest follows by the Eberlein- Šmulian theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People add separability because in that case the proof is easier and is known as Helly's Selection Theorem. One can give a proof independent of the usual proof of Banach Alaoglu which uses Tykonov's Theorem. One proceeds by a diagonalization argument by exploiting separability. Actually, a Banach Space is separable if and only if the unit ball in weak$^{*}$ topology is metrizable. Thus showing sequential compactness suffices.

Suppose you have proved the statement:

> In a separable and reflexive Banach Space, a bounded sequence has a
> weakly convergent subsequence

Consider now $X$ to be a reflexive banach space and  and let $x_{n}$ to be a bounded sequence. Then consider $V=\overline{\text{span}}\{x_{1},..x_{n},...\}$. Then, $V$ itself is a reflexive and separable Banach space and hence has a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ that converges weakly to some $x_{0}\in V$.

Now let $f\in V^{*}$ be a linear functional, then $f(x_{n_{k}})\to f(x_{0})$. By Hahn-Banach Theorem, $f$ has an extension $f'\in X^{*}$ such that $f'|_{V}=f$. Then we have $f'(x_{n_{k}})\to f(x_{0})$ . Also for any linear functional $F\in X^{*}$, we have that $F|_{V}$ is a bounded linear functional in $V^{*}$. Thus $F(x_{n_{k}})\to F(x_{0})$ .

Thus we have that $f(x_{n_{k}})\to f(x_{0})$ for all linear functionals $f\in X^{*}$. Thus $x_{n_{k}}$ converges weakly to $x_{0}$ .

Thus, extending from the separable case to the non-separable case is not really difficult.